# Counting sequences of letters containing an odd number of As

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics

I'm working through my maths work and I've come to the following question..
[image]

I'm having trouble visualizing part (C). Heres the official answer...

[image]

Why wouldn't it be it be odd?  Just because the last letter is an A, why wouldnt it be AAA A

Thanks for any help

Comment: I've just realised that the question is referring to Xn which is an odd numbers of A's, so you take 1 off then its going to be even.

Answer (score 0):

If $x_n$has an odd number of 'A's 
and the last letter of the sequence is an A
Then that means if there are an other A's it has to be even
(Even +odd) = even,  since 1 is odd that means 
 $x_{n-1}$has an even number of A's